# why can I still give const value a new value

Tags: c++, constants, jupyter, xeus-cling

[image]The book said I cannot change the value of const once I gave it a number， but it seems I can still give it a number even if it was given.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int fansc(100);
cout<< fansc << endl; //output:100
int fansc(20);
cout<< fansc << endl;//output:20
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, which means it's not the code you're running. Please make a [mre]

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/KWh7s1nzh

Comment: @cigien I'm using anaconda on Mac to practice the c++, maybe it's the problem of this compiler.

Comment: Oh, you're not using a compiler at all. You appear to be using some interpreter instead. You can edit your question to include those details, but I would *strongly* suggest using an actual compiler. An interpreter lets you do things that are just not valid C++, as you've shown in the code.

Comment: Because of the incremental compiler, the code in question is probably equivalent to this: https://godbolt.org/z/TYasnYWzh

Comment: *"The book"* -- which book? And does the book cover Anaconda? If it covers just regular C++, then it does not apply to your situation. (Regular C++ would, for example, require that the line `cout<< fansc << endl;` be inside a function. Your line is not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ code you gave won't compile, and rightly so. A `const` variable<sup>(a)</sup> is, well, ... constant. The error is shown in the following program and transcript:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int fansc(100);
    cout << fansc << endl;
    int fansc(20);
    cout << fansc << endl;
}
```

```sh
pax> g++ --std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o prog prog.cpp
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6:9: error: conflicting declaration ‘int fansc’
    6 |     int fansc(20);
      |         ^~~~~
prog.cpp:4:15: note: previous declaration as ‘const int fansc’
    4 |     const int fansc(100);
      |               ^~~~~
```

That leaves the Anaconda bit that you mention in a comment. I have little experience with that but it seems to me the only way that would work is if the second `fansc` definition was somehow created in a different *scope* to the first. In real C++ code, that would go something like:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int fansc(100);
    cout << fansc << endl;
    { // new scope here
        int fansc(20);
        cout << fansc << endl;
    } // and ends here
    cout << fansc << endl;
}
```

And the output of that is:

```sh
pax> g++ --std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o prog prog.cpp && ./prog
100
20
100
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, I *know* that's a self-contradiction :-)

Comment: Does the second code mean that you used the brace make "int fans(20)" as a block. Once out of the block, the fansc(20) will be disposed and the value of fansc is 100.

Comment: @ryw: yes, the "20" `fansc` is accessible only within its scope, which is bounded by the inner braces. After the inner closing brace, any use of the identifier `fansc` will refer to the "100" variant. I've adjusted the second code snippet to show this.

Comment: Minor note, but this has nothing to do with Anaconda or Conda *per se*. Issue is more about Jupyter and the (presumably) [xeus-cling C++ kernel](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling) being used as an interpreter.

Comment: @ryw: Clearer: The second code opens a new scope, which allows it to create a second entirely new variable that also happens to be named `fans`. Inside this new scope, the name `fans` now refers to the second variable isntead of the first